# Windows Batch - Update the variable in the IF loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to figure out what version of my software is installed on user's computer. The versions are 5.0, 4.0, 3.0. Version **5.0 is the latest**.

- I would like to check if the user has any of these versions installed in this order.
- I have wrote a script as follows: I also added `setlocal enabledelayexpansion` at the top.
- I have learnt here (on stackoverlow) that I need to use `!variable!` to change the value of variable `VERSION` in the IF loop.
- I tried it myself, but most of the examples were for echo'ing.
- Here I am changing the value of the **version**.
- Then update the **path** directory.

I am not able to make this work. Can you please help. Thank you so much.

Here is my script:

```
:: Find the version installed in the user's computer
:: valid versions are 5.0, 4.0, 3.0 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO OFF
SET "error_code=0"

::  Latest Software version
    SET VERSION=5.0
    echo checking SOFTWARE Version: %VERSION%

::  build a path and check if it exists

SET "PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\%VERSION%"
call:CHECK_IF_VALID "%PATH%"

if %error_code% == 1 (

::  check v.4    
    SET VERSION=4.0
    echo checking SOFTWARE Version: !VERSION!
    SET "PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\%VERSION%"
    call:CHECK_IF_VALID "%PATH%"

    if %error_code% == 1 (

    ::  check v.3 
        SET VERSION=3.0
        echo checking SOFTWARE Version: !VERSION!
        SET "PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\%VERSION%"
        call:CHECK_IF_VALID "%PATH%"

        if %error_code% == 1 (          
            echo.&pause&goto:eof
        )
    )
)

::  Function to check if path exists    
    :CHECK_IF_VALID

    if not exist %1 (
       echo version not found...
       set "error_code=1"
     ) else echo. Version found...       
     echo.

goto:eof
EXIT
```

Comment: You should not change the general path variable - choose a different name for your app. If you **want** to change the path variable persistently edit the registry or use setx and leave the present entries in the path unless you now what you are doing.

Comment: Are `\MYSOFT\5.0`, `\MYSOFT\4.0` and `MYSOFT\3.0` supposed to be file names or directory names?

Comment: @LotPings I apologize I should have used a better variable name. (I do have a better name). I just was trying to strip off all additional things to make it available for Stackoverflow question. Thank you.

Comment: @Cricrazy, could you answer my question please!

Comment: @Compo they  `\mysoft\5.0`, `mysoft\4.0` etc are the folder names.

Comment: Because you are checking for the existence of directories your `If Exist` as well as those in the current answers should end with a back slash. `If Exist "DirectoryName\" …` as opposed to `If Exist "FileName"…` As a side note why would you create a piece of software and not utilise a file, registry data or function to eaily detect its version? Checking for a fixed foldername seems a poor choice.

Answer (score 1):

`path` refers to the path-sequence that windows searches to find an executable if it's not found in *this* directory. Not a good idea to change it. Not good at all.

`::` is a broken label and labels are not allowed in (parenthesised sequences of commands) or `code blocks` - use `rem` instead.

You need to use `!var!` within a `code block` whenever you need to access the modified value of `var` within that code block. `%var%` accesses the **original** value of `var` (when the code block was encountered)

Hence,

```
set "versionfound="
for %%v in (5.0 4.0 3.0) do if not defined versionfound (
 if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\%%v" set "versionfound=%%v"
)
if defined versionfound (echo %versionfound% found) else (echo not found)
```

should detect the version. It substitutes the three possibilities into the string in turn and detects whether that version exists. If it does, `versionfound` is set to the version that is found (having been initialised to *nothing*) and thereafter, the check is skipped because `if defined` uses the current value in the environment (value set or value not set).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simpler :

Create a `list` with all version, and `loop` on all the version testing the `path`.

```
@echo off
set "$version=3.0 4.0 5.0"
SET "$PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\"

::Checking if a version is installed

for %%a in (%$version%) do (
    echo Checking Version : %%a
    if exist "%$PATH%%%a" (
        echo VERSION IS : %%a
        goto:eof
    )
)

echo No version Found !!
```

If various version can be installed on the same machine then we cath the last :

```
@echo off
set "$version=3.0 4.0 5.0"
SET "$PATH=%PROGRAMFILES%\MYSOFT\"
set "$LastVersion=none"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::Checking if a version is installed

for %%a in (%$version%) do (
    echo Checking Version : %%a
    if exist "%$PATH%%%a" (
        echo VERSION %%a is installed
        set $LastVersion=%%a
    )
)

Echo Last Version Installed : !$LastVersion!
```

Comment: What is the purpose of include the not-alpha `$` char at beginning of variable names? I can see several disadvantages on doing that and not a single advantage...

Comment: This is only a personal way of defining variables that make the code more readable. I don't see any disadvantages to that.